# how to use .mousemove and .mouseenter simultaneity?

Tags: jquery, mousemove, mouseenter

I'm working on a page including mousemove and mouse enter.
Unfortunately I can't get work the both of them.

Here you can check the mousemove(over the ".flight3" div) (the background get blurry and the globe get clear and animated)

```
var timer;
$(".flight3").mousemove(function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }

    $('.flight1,.cycle-slideshow').fadeIn();
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.flight1,.cycle-slideshow').fadeOut()


    }, 320)


})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Je9D6/

Here you can check the mouse enter (over the ".map" div) (the background get blurry and the globe get clear and animated)

```
$(".map").mouseenter(function() {

    $('.flight1,.cycle-slideshow').fadeIn();

    })


$(".map").mouseleave(function() {

    $('.flight1,.cycle-slideshow').fadeOut();

    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Je9D6/1/

When I put the both mouse move and mouse enter, only the mousemove is working.
I also tried with mouseover instead of mouse move : same problem.

Does someone knows what am I doing wrong..??

Thanks a lot

Comment: i'm confused on what exactly you're trying to accomplish? are you trying to trigger the same event on both mousemove and mouseenter? if that's the case, of course mousemove will always continuously fire...you have to move the mouse to get it to enter an element

Comment: Hi yes that what I want to accomplish, but look here http://jsfiddle.net/Je9D6/6/. when hover the globe the mouse move isn't working, that what I want, but I don't understand why the mouse enter does not. What could I do to be able to have the same event on both action..?

Comment: Actually I want the fadeIn when the user move the mouse, and fadeOut when the user stop moving the mouse. But I want the fadein too when the user is hovering the globe, even if the mouse is not moving.. I don't know if I'm understandable ..?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$(".map").on("mouseenter mouseleave",
    function(e) {
        if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
            $('.flight1,.cycle-slideshow').fadeIn();
        }
        else{
            $('.flight1,.cycle-slideshow').fadeOut();
        }           
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Je9D6/4/)

Comment: Hi, 
Thnaks for your answer. My second fiddle was really too sketchy, your code is far more efficient !

Actually I would like to combine the two fiddles. 

http://jsfiddle.net/Je9D6/6/

But only the mousemove is working if I put the both of them.

Do you have a clue .?

Comment: Cause `flight3` covers everything.

Comment: Hi thanks alek, actually no, .flight3 is just under .map (.map got a "z-index" higher than flight3), we can tell that cause the event mousevove does not work when the cursor is on .map… I don't get why the mousemove is stopped by .map but doesn't make the mouseenter to work.